# Adding new build configuration for Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I work on a project that requires the user to authenticate via SSO (Shibboleth) before they can begin using the application. We recently decided to use Create React App (CRA) for the front end of this project but we have found that our development is extremely constrained by CRA as there are really only two build commands:

```
npm run start
```

or

```
npm run build
```

Because **npm run start** spins up a web server which then proxies requests to my backend apache which then proxies requests to SSO, I never end up with the SSO token I need.

I have found a workaround by copying the token in a browser session on the server (directly, not through the web server provided by CRA) and pasting that into a new browser session via the CRA web server. However, that is very cumbersome.

I would like to know if there is any way I can create a new build configuration that will watch my directory for changes, build into the 'build' directory of CRA and NOT minify the js file. Is this possible within the bounds of CRA or do I need to eject?

Answer (score 0):

[As CRA docs says](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject): you can't create custom build configuration with CRA. You have to move to pure weback. Fortunatelly here is a qucik comand for that: `npm run eject`.